# Exercise 7 page 93 Functional Analysis book of Conway

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

The following is Exercise 7 page 93 in Functional Analysis book of Conway:

> Let $1 \le p \le \infty$ and suppose $(a_{ij})$ is a matrix such that $(Af)(i) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{ij} f(j)$ defines an element $Af$ of $\ell^p$ for every $f$ in $\ell^p$. Show that $A \in \mathcal{B}(\ell^p)$.

Case $p=\infty$: If $f(j)$ is such that $||f(j)||_{\infty} < \infty$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{ij} f(j) < \infty $ how to show that $(Af)(i)$ is bounded so that A maps $\ell^{\infty}$ to $\ell^{\infty}$?

Case $1 \le p < \infty$ : For this case same approach I think but this time we use Holder's inequality I suppose?

**NOTE :** I looking for a solution based on the Uniform Boundedness Principle, a solution **without** using the Closed Graph Theorem. The answer in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947971/show-that-the-map-a-lp-rightarrow-lq-is-a-bounded-linear-map) has just one sentence mentioning that the result could be proved using Baire Category Theorem, but such mention is not really an answer. The answer itself is based on applying the Closed Graph Theorem.

Comment: One approach is the uniform boundedness principle.

Answer (score 3):

For $p \in [1, +\infty]$, let $q \in [1, +\infty]$, such that $\frac1p +\frac1q =1$, (with the usual convention that $\frac1\infty=0$).

It is immediate that $A$ is linear. So it remains to be proved that $A$ is bounded.

For all $i$ and $k$ positive integers, let us define $\phi_{i k}$ on $\ell^p$ by, for all $f \in \ell^p$,
$$ \phi_{i k}(f) = \sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}f(j) $$
It is clear that $\phi_{i k}$ is linear. Note that, for each $i$ and $k$, we have that $(a_{ij})_{j=1}^k \in \ell^q$. So $\phi_{i k}$ is bounded linear and $\| \phi_{i k} \| = \| (a_{ij})_{j=1}^k \|_q$ (see **Remark**).

Now, note that, for all $f \in \ell^p$, $\sup_{i, k} | \phi_{i k}(f) | < \infty$. So, by the Uniform Boundness Principle,
$$\sup_{i, k} \| \phi_{i k} \| < \infty$$
that is,
$\sup_{i, k} \| (a_{ij})_{j=1}^k \|_q < \infty$. Let $M =\sup_{i, k} \| (a_{ij})_{j=1}^k \|_q < \infty$.
It follows that
$$ \sup_{i} \| (a_{ij})_{j=1}^\infty \|_q \leq M < \infty$$

Now,, for each $i$ positive integer, let us define $\phi_i$ on $\ell^p$ by, for all $f \in \ell^p$,
$$ \phi_i(f) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}f(j) $$
It is clear that $\phi_i$ is linear and, for all $f \in \ell^p$,
$$ |\phi_i(f)| \leq \| (a_{ij})_{j=1}^\infty \|_q \|f\|_p \leq M \|f\|_p $$
So $\phi_i$ is bounded.

For each $i$  positive integer, let $e_i \in \ell^p$ be such that $e_i = (e_{i,j})_{j=1}^\infty$ and $e_{i,i} = 1$ and $e_{i,j}=0$ if $i \ne j$.

Now, for each $r$ positive integer, let us define $\psi_r$ on $\ell^p$ by, for all $f \in \ell^p$,
$$ \psi_r(f) = \sum_{i=1}^r \phi_i(f) e_i \in  \ell^p $$
It is clear that $\psi_r$ is linear and bounded. Moreover,
$$ \sup_r \|\psi_r(f) \|_p \leq \|Af\|_p < \infty$$
So, by the Uniform Boundness Principle, we have that
$$ \sup_r \|\psi_r \|_{\mathcal{B}(\ell^p, \ell^p)} < \infty$$
Let $K = \sup_r \|\psi_r \|_{\mathcal{B}(\ell^p, \ell^p)} < \infty$.
So, we have, for all $r$ and all $f \in \ell^p$,
$$\|\psi_r(f)\|_p \leq K \|f\|_p \tag{1} $$
Note that, for all $f \in \ell^p$, $\psi_r(f)$ converges to $Af$ in $\ell^p$, so we have that   $\|\psi_r(f)\|_p$ converges to $\|Af\|_p$. Form $(1)$, we have that
$$ \|Af\|_p \leq K \|f\|_p $$
So, $A$ is bounded.

**Remark**:  Since $(a_{ij})_{j=1}^k \in \ell^q$  and, for all $f \in \ell^p$,
$ \phi_{i k}(f) = \sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}f(j) $, we have that $\| \phi_{i k} \| = \| (a_{ij})_{j=1}^k \|_q$. It is a standard result on the duality of $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$.

Comment: Shouldn't be $\| \phi_{i k} \| \le \| (a_{ij})_{j=1}^k \|_q$ and not $\| \phi_{i k} \| = \| (a_{ij})_{j=1}^k \|_q$? I mean how equality is achieved? (though, still boundedness of $\phi_{i k}$ holds but it may affect $\sup_{i, k} \| (a_{ij})_{j=1}^k \|_q < \infty$ few lines later)

Comment: Shouldn't be $\sup_r \|\psi_r(f) \|_p = \|Af\|_p < \infty$, and not $\sup_r \|\psi_r(f) \|_p \leq \|Af\|_p < \infty$ : sup is when $r=\infty$ because of monotonicity?

Comment: @L.G.  Since $(a_{ij})_{j=1}^k \in \ell^q$  and, for all $f \in \ell^p$, 
$ \phi_{i k}(f) = \sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}f(j) $, we have that $\| \phi_{i k} \| = \| (a_{ij})_{j=1}^k \|_q$. It is a standard result on the duality of $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$.

Comment: @L.G. Yes,  $\sup_r \|\psi_r(f) \|_p = \|Af\|_p < \infty$ , but all we need for the proof is just $\sup_r \|\psi_r(f) \|_p \leq \|Af\|_p < \infty$.

Comment: Can you please refer to a reference that I can learn about the Remark you just added?

Comment: @L.G.  For $p \in [1, \infty)$, see, for instance, Theorem 13.18 in Buckner's Real Analysis.  Remember that $\ell^p$ is just a special case of $L^p$.

Comment: Splendid! Thanks a lot :)